# How to calculate model weight for GLM-quasi poisson model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, model-comparison, quasi-likelihood

I am running several models with the quasi-Poisson family, I have calculated QAIC for each model but I wanted to know the weight of each individual model. I tried AICcmodavg but it did not work.

Is there a simple function that I can use to calculate the model weights?

this is how I run the model

```r
model <- glm(casualty ~ forest + agri, 
          family = quasipoisson(link = "log"), 
          data = ep)
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to compare quasi-Poisson models is by standard glm hypothesis testing using quasi $F$-tests.
Only nested models can be compared in this way with one model (the null) a simpler case of the other (the alternative).

You cannot compare quasi-glm models using AIC or likelihood because quasi-glms don't have probability distributions or likelihoods.
This means that there is no formal way to compare disjoint models, when neither model is a special case of the other.